# Lucene.Net in Arabic

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net, arabic

Briefly, Is there any Arabic Analyzer that supports Lucene.Net.
As I want to index huge number of Arabic txt files.
Can I use the Standard Analyzer or White Space Analyzer to parse the Arabic Files?

```
analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer();
```

Comment: In contrib section of Lucene.Net there is an ArabicAnalyzer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there any sample code to use it ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucenete.Net.Contrib contains an arabic analyzer at `Lucene.Net.Analysis.Analyzer.ArabicAnalyzer`.

Install it using NuGet:

https://nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Contrib/3.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Lucenete.Net.Contrib contains an Arabic Analyzer but the correct namespace is:

**Lucene.Net.Analysis.AR.ArabicAnalyzer**

See attached screenshot:

[image]